# Converting from and to void* (C++)

Tags: android, c++

I have to call a function that accepts a void* parameter as additional data and two function parameters.

Those two functions receive the additional data.
I want to pack an int and two double arrays into the additional data parameter. I also need to be able to unpack them.

Packing in:

```
double *AffineAndPoints2d;
double *Intrinsics;
int ncams;
...
LOGD("3.4 %d", ncams);
LOGD("3.5 %f", Intrinsics[2]);
LOGD("3.6 %f", AffineAndPoints2d[4]);
void* adata[3];
adata[0]=&ncams;
adata[1]=AffineAndPoints2d;
adata[2]=Intrinsics;
```

Unpacking inside one of the mentioned functions:

```
static void proj_motstr(int j, int i, double *aj, double *bi, double *xij, void *adata)
{
   int *ncams=((int **)&adata)[0];
   double *affineAndPts2D = ((double **)((&adata + sizeof(int *))))[0];
   double *intrinsics = ((double **)((&adata + sizeof(int *))))[1];
   LOGD("4.4 %d", *ncams);
   LOGD("4.5 %f", intrinsics[2]);
   LOGD("4.6 %f", affineAndPts2D[4]);
}
```

All of this is in android JNI, but that is irrelevant.

Output:

```
3.4 3
3.5 -625.041382
3.6 563.992036
4.4 1603595320
4.5 -0.000000
Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x5f2a4c15 (code=1), thread 30116 (Thread-9197)
```

Full code: http://pastebin.com/0YwfVzyA

I have no idea what I'm doing. Please help!

---

Here's updated version of `proj_motstr` that should work.

```
static void proj_motstr(int j, int i, double *aj, double *bi, double *xij, void *adata)
{
   void** in = (void**)data;
   int *ncams=(int *)(in[0]);
   double *affineAndPts2D = (double *)(in[1]);
   double *intrinsics = (double *)(in[2]);

   LOGD("4.4 %d", *ncams);
   LOGD("4.5 %f", intrinsics[2]);
   LOGD("4.6 %f", affineAndPts2D[4]);

   projHybrid(j, i, aj, bi, (double)(*ncams), affineAndPts2D, intrinsics, xij);
}
```

Comment: You need to use: `void** in = (void**)data; int *ncams=(int *)(in[0]); double *affineAndPts2D = (double *)(in[1]); double *intrinsics = (double *)(in[2]);`

Comment: you are welcome. Glad it worked. I have dealt with this pattern a few times in my work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just cast things back from void*:

```
int ncams = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(adata[0]);
double *affineAndPts2D = reinterpret_cast<double*>(adata[1]);
double *intrinsics = reinterpret_cast<double*>(adata[2]);
```